# How to call a function to reload another function (on "orientationchange()" e.g.)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, reload

I want to reload a js function (inside *xyz.php*) as the mobile orientation changes (on `orientationchange()` ).

In a "*jquery-custom.js*" I already have a function for `orientationchange()` that works:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) {
     $(".loader-packery").show().delay(1000).fadeOut(1);
});
```

This is the function inside "*xyz.php*" i want to reload:

```
    function searchWidthMobile() {
        if (is_mobile) {
            var $mobile_search = $( ".mobile-header-inner .searchform" );
            if($mobile_search.length){
                $mobile_search.focusin(function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        'z-index':'2'
                    }).stop().animate({
                        'padding-left':'0px',
                        'padding-right':'0px'
                    }, 400);
                });

                if ($(document).width() > 380) {
                    $mobile_search.focusout(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        'padding-left':'435px',
                        'padding-right':'77px'
                    },400);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $mobile_search.css({
                            'z-index':'0'
                        });
                    }, 400);
                });
                }
                else {
                    $mobile_search.focusout(function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({
                        'padding-left':'235px',
                        'padding-right':'77px'
                    },400);
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $mobile_search.css({
                            'z-index':'0'
                        });
                    }, 400);
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    }

    searchWidthMobile();
    //        $(window).resize(searchWidthMobile);
```

The function in xyz.php works. But as you can imagine, only on loading or reloading the site itself.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. You say you already have a handler executed when an orientationchange event is thrown. Great. and you have a function you want to get executed then (I assume that is what you mean by "reload"). So what is the question? Just call the function inside the handler.

Comment: I know..I don't know all the terms.. I'm trying to do what tommy answered. But somehow this seems to do nothing. But yeah right, I'm trying to execute the searchWidthMobile() again on orientation change. It already loads once on loading the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the function when the device orientation changes:

```
$(window).on('orientationchange', function(e) {
    $(".loader-packery").show().delay(1000).fadeOut(1);
    searchWidthMobile();
});
```

Comment: Have you checked for any errors in the developer console?

Comment: Just did. No errors. It is a wordpress child theme tho. Don't know if that's relevant.

Comment: What happens if you manually call `searchWidthMobile();` in the console?

Comment: Thinks I never heared of :D Okay, that gives an error. Do I have to define searchWidthMobile in the custom.js?

`Uncaught ReferenceError: searchWidthMobile is not defined(…)

(anonymous function) @ VM1554:2InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ 

VM1552:875InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ 

VM1552:808InjectedScript.evaluate @ VM1552:664`

Comment: Your function is not available. You either do not load the script or you've wrapped it in an anonymous function. Make sure you add the script with the function to your site.